# I can't change collation in c# to store Persian words

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, collation

I want to store some Persian (Farsi) words in C# local database , but after storing I see just some `??????`.

I know it is because of its collation but I don't know how to change it. In the table properties collation is not active and I can't change it.

Comment: What server? Show some code on how you save it?

Comment: You need to make sure to use the `nvarchar` datatype for any columns in SQL Server that need to hold Unicode characters, and if you're inserting this using raw SQL with string literals, you must ensure all Unicode string literals are prefixed with an `N` (`declare @string nvarchar(10) = N'....'`)